# Loop through code batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have done a batch file to help me doing a measurement but I don't know how to put it in a for-loop to make it for n times and to change the name of the folder in "Results" as it changes in the for loop (here I have 01 but just for one measurement time without for loop).

This is the code that I have done:

```
@echo off
@set var1=var1.exe
@set var2=C:\...\...\... .txt
@set Results=C:\....\Results\01
Mkdir %Results%
%var1%     %var2%     %Results%
```

I tried to use this code:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO (
@echo off
@set var1=var1.exe
@set var2=C:\...\...\... .txt
@set Results=C:\....\Results\%%A
Mkdir %Results%
%var1%     %var2%     %Results%   
)
```

Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,10) DO call :doit %%A
goto :eof

:doit
set pad=00%1
set num=%pad:~-2%
@set var1=var1.exe
@set var2=C:\...\...\... .txt
@set Results=C:\....\Results\%num%
Mkdir %Results%
%var1%     %var2%     %Results%   
goto :eof
```

Comment: IT is working very well except one thing that I want the first 10 Results folders to be called 01,02,.....09 as I wrote in the beginning "01"

Comment: fixed for you by adding padding and read most right chars from a parameter

Comment: that's perfect thank you very much but please give me an explanation for the two lines that I wrote for you 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the things like **:menu** etc..
And when you want to loop, just put **goto menu**